# Counting the number of occurrences. (beginner)

Tags: java, counter, coin-flipping

Okay, I'm a beginner with java and struggling with the counter. I am trying to find the count and print the number of occurrences of both heads and tails of a flipped coin. When I run my code, it prints the occurrence of each event on every line. I want it to be a cumulative count and print at the very end. If you can help thanks! Ps: I also haven't implemented the tailCounter yet because I want to figure out heads first.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InClass7_1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int flipcount;
        Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter a number of times to flip the coin");
        flipcount = scannerObject.nextInt();

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter <= flipcount)
        {
            System.out.print("Flip number " + counter + ": ");
            int coinFlip = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
            int headCounter = 0;
            int tailCounter = 0;

            if (coinFlip == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
            }
            counter++;

            if (coinFlip == 1)
                headCounter++;

            System.out.println("Times head was flipped: " + headCounter);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation would make your code a lot easier to read. You want your code to be readable if you would like people to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `headCounter` and `tailCounter` variables above the while-loop and increment according to their appearance in your if-else construct. Move the print statement below the while-loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int flipcount;
    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number of times to flip the coin");
    flipcount = scannerObject.nextInt();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int counter = 1;
    int headCounter = 0;
    int tailCounter = 0;
    while (counter <= flipcount) {
        System.out.print("Flip number " + counter + ": ");
        int coinFlip = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
        if (coinFlip == 1) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            headCounter++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tailCounter++;
        }
        counter++;            
    }
    System.out.println("Times head was flipped: " + headCounter);
    System.out.println("Times tails was flipped: " + tailCounter);
}
```